# How To Add Item To An Array From Another Class VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Okay, so I have a class element, and a form.

I have an **Array** inside my class element, and I need it to set it from a form...

basically what I'm doing:

----Form1----

```
*DataClass.VarArray()*
```

---

----DataClass----

```
Public VarArray() As String
```

---

And I need to know, how do I add an item to an array, and also how to get it from another class... Please

I Already Tried Different Methods, Like Making A List But that Did not work

Comment: This is not a question worthy of SO.  Telling us that you tried different things is not what you need to do.  You need to show us what you think is the correct way and tell us what happened when you tried it.  You might start with actually learning how arrays work because, based on what you've shown us, there is no array.  Arrays are objects, like any other, so a variable that can refer to an array is not an array.

Comment: For example Form1 has Public Array1, then on Form2 you do Form1.Array1 + something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEW:

So, I **added** a TextBox and a RichTextBox to the form...

TextBoxUserName(TextBox): contains the username that we are going to enter to the list

TextBoxListOfUsers(RichTextBox): contains the usernames addedd throught the button... is only to get a view of what we are doing.

Now when you click the NewUserBT button you will add a string (the user name) to the list if is not blank, white spaces, is not yet contained ecc...

Check out and tell me...

```
Public Class Form1
    ' Declare "usersClass" and its type
    Dim usersClass As DataClass

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ' now give to "usersClass" a value, an instance, so...
        usersClass = New DataClass()
    End Sub

    Public Sub NewUserBT_Click() Handles NewUserBT.Click
        Dim new_user As String = Me.TextBoxUserName.Text

        ' If is not blank, empty or white spaces, and is not contained in the list...
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(new_user) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(new_user) AndAlso Not Me.usersClass.usersNameList.Contains(new_user) Then
            usersClass.usersNameList.Add(new_user)
            Me.TextBoxListOfUsers.Text += new_user + vbCrLf ' name + linefeed
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataClass
    ' Declare "usersNameList" var and its type
    Public usersNameList As List(Of String)

    Public Sub New()
        ' When we "usersClass = New DataClass()" we will go here and set the instance of userNameList
        usersNameList = New List(Of String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

OLD:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim foo As ArrayClass

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        foo = New ArrayClass()
    End Sub

    Public Sub pippo() Handles Button1.Click
        foo.array(1) = "something"
        Button1.Text = foo.array(1)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ArrayClass
    Public array(10) As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

This might be what you are looking for... I think.
You can use the array in the form class, give it a try.

Tip:

```
Dim strings_list As List(Of String) ' this is a list of strings
Dim strings_array(10) As String ' this is an array to hold 10 strings
```

Comment: yea, but since basically have to make something that can always expand more (starting from 0, to infinite items) i think it would be better to do a list.. right?

Comment: Yeah, I will update my answer soon. Try to use Dim list as List(Of String).

Comment: How you want to manage the list? From a button click, from a string field... tell me because I can't understand...

Comment: basically, i have a form that has a TextBox, whenever i click the "generateUser" button it adds the text used in the TextBox to the public list i defined in the dataclass.

Comment: DataClass Code: https://imgur.com/UoeJAXR

A Bit of Form1 Code: https://imgur.com/vnWzOPZ

Comment: Ok maybe later I can review my answer, otherwise I ll update at 9 utc tomorrow

Comment: ok, just tried it out and... apparently it works. Now i have to store it in a file, and if i cant make it into a file, i'll make another post. Thanks really much.